# Semantic search with NLP and elasticsearch

Tags: search, nlp

I am experimenting with elasticsearch as a search server and my task is to build a "semantic" search functionality. From a short text phrase like "I have a burst pipe" the system should infer that the user is searching for a plumber and return all plumbers indexed in elasticsearch.

Can that be done directly in a search server like elasticsearch or do I have to use a natural language processing (NLP) tool like e.g. Maui Indexer. What is the exact terminology for my task at hand, text classification? Though the given text is very short as it is a search phrase.

Comment: I suggest you to use  BERT embedding to add embedding record to elasticSearch similar to what is explained in https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There may be several approaches with different implementation complexity.

The easiest one is to create **list of topics** (like plumbing), attach **bag of words** (like "pipe"), identify search request by majority of keywords and search only in specified topic (you can add field `topic` to your elastic search documents and set it as mandatory with `+` during search).

Of course, if you have lots of documents, manual creation of topic list and bag of words is very time expensive. You can use **machine learning** to automate some of tasks. Basically, it is enough to have distance measure between words and/or documents to automatically discover topics (e.g. by **data clustering**) and **classify** query to one of these topics. Mix of these techniques may also be a good choice (for example, you can manually create topics and assign initial documents to them, but use classification for query assignment). Take a look at Wikipedia's article on [**latent semantic analysis**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) to better understand the idea. Also pay attention to the 2 linked articles on [data clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_clustering) and [document classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification). And yes, [Maui Indexer](http://code.google.com/p/maui-indexer/) may become good helper tool this way.

Finally, you can try to build an engine that "understands" meaning of the phrase (not just uses terms frequency) and searches appropriate topics. Most probably, this will involve **natural language processing** and **ontology-based knowledgebases**. But in fact, this field is still in active research and without previous experience it will be very hard for you to implement something like this.

Comment: Any solution should have Transformers BERT involved at least for building the embeddings.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to explore https://blog.conceptnet.io/2016/11/03/conceptnet-5-5-and-conceptnet-io/.

It combines `semantic networks` and `distributional semantics`.

> When most developers need word embeddings, the first and possibly only place they look is word2vec, a neural net algorithm from Google that computes word embeddings from distributional semantics. That is, it learns to predict words in a sentence from the other words around them, and the embeddings are the representation of words that make the best predictions. But even after terabytes of text, there are aspects of word meanings that you just won’t learn from distributional semantics alone.

Some results

> The ConceptNet Numberbatch word embeddings, built into ConceptNet 5.5, solve these SAT analogies better than any previous system. It gets 56.4% of the questions correct. The best comparable previous system, Turney’s SuperSim (2013), got 54.8%. And we’re getting ever closer to “human-level” performance on SAT analogies — while particularly smart humans can of course get a lot more questions right, the average college applicant gets 57.0%.

Answer (score 3):

Semantic search is basically search with meaning. Elasticsearch uses JSON serialization by default, to apply search with meaning to JSON you would need to extend it to support edge relations via JSON-LD. You can then apply your semantic analysis over the JSON-LD schema to word disambiguate plumber entity and burst pipe contexts as a subject, predicate, object relationships. Elasticsearch has a very weak semantic search support but you can go around it using faceted searching and bag of words. You can index a thesaurus schema for plumbing terms, then do a semantic matching over the text phrases in your sentences.

Answer (score 2):

*["Elasticsearch 7.3 introduced introduced text similarity search with vector fields"](https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch)*.

They describe the application of using text embeddings (e.g., [word embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) and [sentence embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_embedding)) to implement this sort of semantic similarity measure.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but part II of [this blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/big-fast-nlp-with-elasticsearch-72ffd7ef8f2e) seems to address this through "contextual searches". It basically makes a two-part query to Elasticsearch in order to build a list of "seed" documents and then an expanded query via the `more-like-this` API. The result is a set of documents most contextually similar to the search query.

Answer (score 2):

it's possible. This GitHub repo shows how to integrate Elasticsearch with the current state-of-the-art on NLP for semantic representation of language: BERT (Bidirectional Encoder Representations from Transformers) https://github.com/Hironsan/bertsearch

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use BERT embedding for your sentences and add an embedding field to your ElasticSearch, as it is described in https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch

For BERT embedding I suggest to use sentence-transformers from Huggingface library. You can find sample codes in https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-a-semantic-search-engine-with-transformers-and-faiss-dcbea307a0e8

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for that:

1. You can perform it in elasticsearch itself. Elasticsearch supports the indexing of Dense Embedding of docs. From there, you can write your own pipeline for search and use your preferred relevancy score formula ie. cosine similarity or something else.
2. Use Haystack pipeline, refer to my [blog](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/leaping-into-semantic-neural-search-with-elasticsearch-faiss-using-haystack-a198c31ea07b) which describes setting up a semantic search pipeline (end-to-end).
3. You can use [Meta's Faiss](https://ai.facebook.com/tools/faiss/)